# Bag to Depth Matrix

Tags: ros

I am working with the Persee 3D camera from Orbecc. I am currently having problems with the processing of the bag files. Someone has provided some code here: https://github.com/JaouadROS/bagtodepth. I tried looking over this and I can't quite make heads or tails of this. I really only have two main questions:

1: Where is the output being saved to? Will it be saved into one of his directories or will it be output somewhere else?

2: Is the output a sort of stream or will it just convert the data to a certain point?

I have successful downloaded (catkin_ws directory) and ran the program with the Persee, but it doesn't help if I can't access the output. I am looking to access this matrix in real time and was hoping I could just adapt his code to my project. He does mention something about information being stored at depthclean. Sadly, the guy that has posted this has not replied to any of the messages that I have sent. Thanks!

Comment: `depthclean` refers to a member variable in the `BagToDepth` class (see `bag_depth.h`). To access it, call the method `getMatTrueDepth()` in your code (see `bag_to_depth.cpp`). The main executable file, `bag_to_depth_main.cpp`, showsn an example of how to use the class.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I would then need to call the getMatTrueDepth at timed intervals to get the updated depth or would it give access to a sort of stream that I can then use?

Comment: You should either ask the author or study the code yourself to find out what it does in detail.